# Google maps real time route and show route history

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

1) I am finding a way to show real time location updates to user with polyline on the map.I have done that but its not accurate.Below is the GIF which show what i am trying to achieve.

Example :

[image]

2) Also once the user is done with it, i need to save the route and show it again by drawing on the map with polylines.

Below is what i have done.

On click on Button i trigger the the location updates with `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10sec`and `0 meters`

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (flag == 0)  //when the first update comes, we have no previous points,hence this
        {
            prev = current;
            flag = 1;
        }
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 18);
        googleMap.animateCamera(update);
        googleDirection = new GoogleDirection(new TaskCompleted() {
            @Override
            public void callBack(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
                addPolyLineToMap(routes);
            }
        });
        googleDirection.execute(prev, current, "mode=walking");
        prev = current;
    }
```

`googleDirection` is just a API call with Lat,Long and Mode of travelling.
`addPolyLineToMap` is a method which adds polylines to map.

Please help to optimize my logic

Answer (score 0):

You said that GoogleDirection is just a API and addPolyLineToMap is method. So I understand it’s not proper to insert that code in onLocationChanged method which fired when user’s location changed. You can divide that functions to optimize your code by method,

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    current = location;
    //Update Map or UpdateUI
    updateCamera();
    updatePolyline();
}

private void updateCamera(){ // }
private void updatePolyline(){ // }
```

You can find the full source code in this link, although it’s Pubnub source however it would be helpful.
Link : https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-12-broadcasting-realtime-location-data-for-android-live-updating-map/